# What are the scenarios that can cause APNS push notifications to fail?

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am trying to built a retry mechanism for APNS push notifications.
Hence I want to collect all the apns device tokens that fail during APNS push.

So far, I am not sure which all scenarios should i consider for a retry as an invalid device token should never be retried.

Also there is no point in retrying if apns port gets blocked or apns server is down.

I have gone through the APNS documentation on Apples site.

Please suggest, which all failure scenarios can be there, when i need to retry the apns push.

Comment: If i recall APNS only gives confirmation that their server received message. There is no way to find out if the end user received the message. So in other words, forget about the retry feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apart from the user message confirmation, should I have the retry feature for a scenario of 1. invalid token, 2. Connection absence to the server..... Apns gives an error message and code for every transmission, also does it gives success and transmission success.